# Unclear on making an API call after authentication?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, egnyte

I am looking on how to use an APIs, more specifically Egnyte's API.

From their documentation, I must first get a oauth2 token, which I was able to get successfully.

Here are their documentation:

- https://developers.egnyte.com/docs/read/Getting_Started
- https://developers.egnyte.com/docs/User_Management_API_Documentation#Get-User-List

However, I am not sure what to do afterwards. I am trying to use their User management API, which I am suppose to make a call to:

https://{Egnyte Domain}.egnyte.com/pubapi/v2/users

However, how do i use their token for a requests.get call to their api?
Below is my python code, I am using the the Requests Module (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests

api_key = 'MY_API_KEY'
username = 'myUserName'
password = 'myPassword'

payload = {
    'grant_type': 'password',
    'client_id': api_key,
     'username': username,
    'password': password
}

token = requests.post("https://{Egnyte Domain}.egnyte.com/puboauth/token", params = payload)

print r.text
```

The response I get is:

```
{"access_token":"*MYToken","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":-1}
```

Thanks!

Comment: When using `requests` save yourself the headaches and use [`requests-oauthlib`](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) too. It'll provide yuo with a `requests` session object that'll add the token automatically once authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, someone had showed me.

had to do minor adjustments to the script:

```
r = requests.post("https://{Egnyte Domain}.egnyte.com/puboauth/token", params=payload)
token = r.json()['access_token']

users = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % token})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the token in the authorization header of requests. The best thing would be to create a persistent connection.

```
r = requests.post("https://{Egnyte Domain}.egnyte.com/puboauth/token", params=payload)
if r.ok:
    access_token = r.json()['access_token']

session = requests.Session()
session.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer %s" % access_token
users = session.get('https://{Egnyte Domain}.egnyte.com/pubapi/v2/users')
```

OR

```
headers = {"Authorization":"Bearer %s" % access_token}
requests.get('https://{Egnyte Domain}.egnyte.com/pubapi/v2/users', headers=headers)
```